# TypeError: app.getGreeting is not a function

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I'm trying to connect a NodeJs server to a solidity contract thats been migrated to a local blockchain and then call the methods on this class via javascript. However, the code returns an error stating that `getGreeting()` is not defined.

I'm very new Solidity and JavaScript (background in C and Java) so I feel like I'm overlooking something really simple?

My question is how to get it to work and find the method and return "Hello, World!" to the terminal?

My development environment is:

- Truffle v5.1.10 (core: 5.1.10)
- Solidity - 0.4.25 (solc-js)
- Node v12.14.1
- Web3.js v1.2.1

Below is the code I'm working on:

```
// import our compiled JSON
const contractJSON = require("./build/contracts/Hello.json");
const contract = require("@truffle/contract");
const Web3 = require('web3');

// create instance of ganache-cli provider
const web3 = new Web3("http://localhost:9545");

var Hello = contract(contractJSON);

Hello.setProvider(web3);

// if contract is deployed return instance of it and store in app variable
let app = Hello.deployed().then((instance) =>{
    return instance;

}).catch(function(error) {
    return error;
});

// call a method on our contract via javascript 
app.getGreeting().then(() => {
    console.log(app);  
});
```

For context the Solidity contract is as follows:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.7.0;

contract Hello {

    string greeting;

    constructor() public {
        greeting = "Hello, World!";
    }

    function getGreeting() public view returns (string memory) {
        return greeting;
    }

    function setGreeting(string memory _greeting) public {
        greeting = _greeting;
    }
}
```

Comment: `app` is a Promise, and Promises don't have a `getGreeting` method. This should work: `app.then(instance => instance.getGreeting()).then(...);`

Comment: @blex Thanks for your input, I've tried something similar `app.then(instance => instance.getGreeting()).then(console.log);` However, i still get the same error...`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: instance.getGreeting is not a function`

Comment: Then is it possible that `instance.getGreeting` returns a String, not a function? Try logging `instance.getGreeting` without `()`

Comment: @blex Ok, I changed the code to not call a function like suggested but it returns `undefined` in the terminal. Any suggestions? I appreciate the help.

Comment: Weird, this seems impossible. If it were really undefined, you would get the error `Cannot read property 'getGreeting' of undefined`, and not `instance.getGreeting is not a function`. What happens if you log the instance [like this](https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/i9upxTEP)?

Comment: @blex Yeah its really got me in a slump. It "compiles" fine with nodejs. It doesn't return any errors but it doesn't log anything out to the terminal hmmm...

It works inside the truffle(develop) console but breaks in a javascript file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206745/discussion-between-blex-and-mondo192).

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who view this in the future the issue was that I imported the provider incorrectly according to the @truffle/contract documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@truffle/contract). Also, forgot to fulfill the second promise. Therefore the answer to this solution as of the time of writing is as follows:

```
const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:9545");

let Hello = contract(contractJSON);
Hello.setProvider(provider);

Hello.deployed().then((instance) => {
    deployed = instance;
    return instance.getGreeting();
}).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Many thanks to @blex for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Your are calling the function "getGreeting()" on the Promise object and not on the contract instance.

```
// import our compiled JSON
const contractJSON = require("./build/contracts/Hello.json");
const contract = require("@truffle/contract");
const Web3 = require('web3');

// create instance of ganache-cli provider
const web3 = new Web3("http://localhost:9545");

var Hello = contract(contractJSON);

Hello.setProvider(web3);

(async () => {
    // Get Contract Instance
    let app = await Hello.deployed();
    // Call Function
    const response = await app.getGreeting();
    console.log(response);
})()
```